# Question: Problem to improve GBM (gradient boosting) model and nan's generated using gbm function in r. train.fraction correctly set to <1

Tags: r, model, training-data, gbm

I am trying to test different parameters in the function gbm of R in order to make predictions with my data . I have a huge table of 79866 rows and 1586 columns where columns are counts for motifs in the DNA and rows indicate diferent regions/positions in the DNA and the organism to which the counts belong. There are only 3 organism but the counts are sepatated by the positions(peakid).

data looks like this:

chrII:11889760_11890077 worm 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...

As I have problems with the memory that I don't know how to solve yet (because of the size of the table) so I am using a subset of the data:

```
motifs.table.sub<-motifs.table[1:1000, 1:1000]

set.seed(123)
motifs_split.sub <- initial_split(motifs.table.sub, prop = .7)
motifs_train.sub <- training(motifs_split.sub)
```

I create a table with different parameters to test

```
hyper_grid <- expand.grid( 
  shrinkage = c(.01, .1, .3), 
  interaction.depth = c(1, 3, 5),
  n.minobsinnode = c(5, 10, 15), 
  bag.fraction = c(.65, .8, 1),
  optimal_trees = 0,
  min_RMSE = 0)
```

Then I randomize the training data:

```
random_index.sub <- sample(1:nrow(motifs_train.sub), nrow(motifs_train.sub))
random_motifs_train.sub <- motifs_train.sub[random_index.sub, ]
```

test the different parameters with 1000 trees

```
for(i in 1:nrow(hyper_grid)) {#
  set.seed(123)
  gbm.tune <- gbm(
    formula = organism ~ .,
    distribution = "gaussian", #default
    data = random_motifs_train.sub,
    n.trees = 1000,
    interaction.depth = hyper_grid$interaction.depth[i],
    shrinkage = hyper_grid$shrinkage[i],
    n.minobsinnode = hyper_grid$n.minobsinnode[i],
    bag.fraction = hyper_grid$bag.fraction[i],
    train.fraction = 0.70,
    n.cores = NULL,
    verbose = V)
  print(head(gbm.tune$valid.error))}
```

The problem is that the model never improves:

Iter TrainDeviance ValidDeviance StepSize Improve

1           nan             nan     0.0100       nan

2           nan             nan     0.0100       nan

3           nan             nan     0.0100       nan

4           nan             nan     0.0100       nan

5           nan             nan     0.0100       nan

6           nan             nan     0.0100       nan

7           nan             nan     0.0100       nan

8           nan             nan     0.0100       nan

9           nan             nan     0.0100       nan

10           nan             nan     0.0100       nan

And values like valid.error are not calculated, they remain as 'NA'. I tried changing the size of the data subset and the same happens with all the parameters I am testing. My data table is huge and it has a lot of zeros, I thouth of removing motifs with low counts but don't think that would help since only 127 motifs out of 1586 have less than 10 counts.

apparently TrainDeviance is nan if train.fraction is not <1: [Gradient Boosting using gbm in R with distribution = "bernoulli"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23530165/gradient-boosting-using-gbm-in-r-with-distribution-bernoulli)

But not my case, I set train.fraction to 0.7

Any ideas of what I am doing wrong?

thanks!

PS: I am following this tutorial: http://uc-r.github.io/gbm_regression

Comment: organism is a factor and you are training on a gaussian? For gbm you have to be clear what is your dependent variable, if say continuous you use gaussian as the distribution, other you use bernoulli for binary.

Comment: Hi, thank you. My response variable is organism (3 options) and I am using gaussian.

Comment: You cannot use Gaussian. It's multi class u need. See example https://rpubs.com/mharris/multiclass_xgboost

Comment: Yeah, I already changed to multi, I had to reduce the data set but now it is improving but I am getting some negative values and nan in the improvement at some number of trees , by any chance do you know what it means?

Comment: verbose looks like this:

Iter   TrainDeviance   ValidDeviance   StepSize   Improve
     1        1.0986          1.0986     0.3000    0.4667
...
   160        0.1370          0.1445     0.3000   -0.0004

   180        0.1351          0.1423     0.3000   -0.0011

   200          -nan            -nan     0.3000      -nan